# How do i select two items from a listview with Robotium?

Tags: android, robotium, listview-selector

I would like two test the selection of two items in a `listview` using Robotium.
I am using this `solo.clickInList(0);` which gets the first item from the list but how do i get the second one. `(solo.clickInList(1);` gets the first one again!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `solo.clickInList(int line, int index)`

This might look like:

`solo.clickInList(0,1)` and `solo.clickInList(0,2)`

Hope this helps!

Comment: HeyThanks for the reply.. but this one gets the first item...  solo.clickInList(0,0); and im unsure how to get the second item.. the code you gave me does not select anything :(

Comment: Its ok... i figured it out by playing with it:                                       this gives the first item : solo.clickInList(1,0); this gives the second item
solo.clickInList(2,0);

Comment: Do you know how i would test drag and drop in a list??